# Exercise to fetch data from JSON files using ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, promise

I did an exercise (self-imposed) promise fetching some data from placeholder JSON files on https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. The exercise in my opinion is finished, but I can't shake the feeling that the code is as dirty as code can be. Please check it out and point me into the right direction and tell me what I did wrong.

The exercise can be found here: http://codepen.io/kresimircoko/pen/vggPmJ

```
'use strict';
const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
const postList = document.querySelector('#post-list');
console.clear();

const commentsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'comments');
    xhr.send();
});

const usersPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'users');
    xhr.send();
});

const postsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'posts');
    xhr.send();
});

// Posts
postsPromise
    .then(data => {
        const posts = JSON.parse(data); // Contains our posts

        usersPromise
            .then(data => {
                const users = JSON.parse(data); // Contains our users
                commentsPromise
                    .then(data => {
                        const comments = JSON.parse(data);
                        displayPosts(posts, users, comments);
                    });
            });
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });

// Users

function displayPosts(posts ,users, comments) {
    let output = '';
    posts.map(post => {
        output += `
            <li class="post"> 
                <h4> ${displayUserName(users, post)} </h4>
                <h3> ${post.title} </h3>
                <p> ${post.body} </p>
                <div class="comment-count"><span> ${displayCommentAmount(comments, post)} comments</span></div>
            </li>
        `;
    });
    postList.innerHTML = output;
}

function displayUserName(users, post) {
    return users.map(user => {
        if (user.id === post.userId) {
            return user.name;
        }
    }).join('');
};

function displayCommentAmount(comments, post) {
     const commentArray = comments.filter(comment => {
        return comment.postId === post.id;
    });
    return commentArray.length;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of things you can do:

1. Use a parameterized function to create the XHR promises, since your three functions are identical other than what they're requesting
2. Use `Promise.all`, since none of the requests relies on information from previous requests and they can run in parallel
3. Move the JSON parsing into the functions retrieving the data, rather than making the consumer of them do it

And a bugfix, I think: The response text is `this.responseText`, not `this.response`, in the XHR load callback.

That would let us replace all of this:

```
const commentsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'comments');
    xhr.send();
});

const usersPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'users');
    xhr.send();
});

const postsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(this.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', root + 'posts');
    xhr.send();
});

// Posts
postsPromise
    .then(data => {
        const posts = JSON.parse(data); // Contains our posts

        usersPromise
            .then(data => {
                const users = JSON.parse(data); // Contains our users
                commentsPromise
                    .then(data => {
                        const comments = JSON.parse(data);
                        displayPosts(posts, users, comments);
                    });
            });
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

with this:

```
const requestJSON = objType => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', root + objType);
        xhr.send();
    });
};

Promise.all([requestJSON('posts'), requestJSON('users'), requestJSON('comments')])
    .then(results => {
        displayPosts(...results);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

So shorter, simpler, and more centralized for debugging, not repeating yourself, etc.

If you want the requests done in series instead of in parallel even though they don't have to be, just change the `Promise.all` part to:

```
requestJSON('posts')
    .then(posts => requestJSON('users')
        .then(users => requestJSON('comments')
            .then(comments => {
                displayPosts(posts, users, comments);
            })
        )
    )
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

*(I tried to keep that in line with your line break/indentation style...)*

Final result (with parallel requests):

```
'use strict';
const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
const postList = document.querySelector('#post-list');
console.clear();

const requestJSON = objType => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.open('GET', root + objType);
        xhr.send();
    });
};

Promise.all([requestJSON('posts'), requestJSON('users'), requestJSON('comments')])
    .then(results => {
        displayPosts(...results);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

// No changes from here on out...

function displayPosts(posts ,users, comments) {
    let output = '';
    posts.map(post => {
        output += `
            <li class="post"> 
                <h4> ${displayUserName(users, post)} </h4>
                <h3> ${post.title} </h3>
                <p> ${post.body} </p>
                <div class="comment-count"><span> ${displayCommentAmount(comments, post)} comments</span></div>
            </li>
        `;
    });
    postList.innerHTML = output;
}

function displayUserName(users, post) {
    return users.map(user => {
        if (user.id === post.userId) {
            return user.name;
        }
    }).join('');
};

function displayCommentAmount(comments, post) {
     const commentArray = comments.filter(comment => {
        return comment.postId === post.id;
    });
    return commentArray.length;
}
```

Comment: `+=` makes the js engine intern a lot of progressively increasing intermediate strings, which is terribly inefficient, so it's better to use `.map` to generate an array then `.join('')` it.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That's more of a comment on the question (or even part of an answer) than a comment on this answer. I limited myself to addressing the promises part of things (based on the title of the question). (It's also *not* always better to build an array and join it, though often it is.)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for that. That part of the code also feels really brittle so I was looking at feedback for that part too :)

Comment: @KrešimirČoko: What I missed in there is that you were *already* using `map`. At the very least you'd want to *either* use `map` and `join` as w0xx0m suggested, or use `forEach` rather than `map` (since you're not using the array it creates). But you might consider any of several templating libraries (or even going further into MVC land with React, Angular, Vue, or ...). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will try it with `forEach` and see where I end up. The current version with the `map` isn't flexible at all. Time to work more on it :) Thank you for the elaborate answer

Comment: @KrešimirČoko: No worries, happy to help. Agreed that part of things isn't flexible, but that wasn't what I meant. `map` loops through the array and creates a *new* array using whatever your callback function returns for each entry. Since you're not returning anything and you're not using the array `map` returns, you'd use `forEach` (leaving everything else exactly the same) there; `map`'s just the wrong function. (Or you'd use `map` and `join` on the result. Or a template lib. Or ... :-) )